# Showing the Careers background in the pdf view

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, jobs, export

I went crazy when I wrote out my background in my Careers profile. Now I want to export it to the PDF view. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your background is something that is typically the topic of a phone screening or a couple of interview questions.  Résumés and CVs exist as way to show your experience and accomplishments at various levels of detail.  We have a good number of features that were designed with the specific intent to give your accomplishments a home on your profile, leaving the background field solely for personal information.  If you feel something personal is important enough include on your Résumé, the personal statement at the top is the perfect place for it.