# Personal Interests section for careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Can we have a "personal interests" section on our Careers profile?  Basically a place **at the end** to put some of our more interesting hobbies and interests (if any).

I figured the background section would be perfect for this, but sadly that section [does not export to pdf](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103929/showing-the-careers-background-in-the-pdf-view)

Comment: Do you want a new section, or do you want the background to export to pdf?

Comment: I suppose either would satisfy the request.  If both are equally easy to implement, I think a new section would be preferable, since background isn't quite the same as personal interests.

Comment: Surely there would be one entry - "Stack Overflow".

Comment: +1, more of my jobs are outside software than inside and some of them are useful on a resume. A personal interest side would help guide viewers of my Careers profile.

Comment: @Oded - honestly, that was actually accurate from [Nov 2011 - Jan 2012](http://stackexchange.com/users/143886/adam-rackis?tab=reputation)

Comment: I HAVE NO PERSONAL INTERESTS I LIVE SOLELY TO WORK I FIND ALL MY FULFILLMENT IN IT HIRE ME NOW